# ESP8266, I am trying to establish a SoftAP and I cant seem to get the WiFilocalIP function to give me my IP

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I am just trying to establish a server and it seems that I can't get the serial monitor to read the local IP of my device and my Client can't establish a connection to update the sensor value. when I run the monitor I get this:

IP Address: (IP unset)

here is my code:

```
    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
    #include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

    /// Config parameters for Access Point
    char * ssid_ap = "This Little Buddy";
    char * password_ap = "guessing";
    IPAddress local_ip(192,168,4,4);
    IPAddress gateway(192,168,4,1);
    IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

    //Setup Server Object
    ESP8266WebServer server;

    //Sensors and what not here
    float sensor_value = 0.0;

    void setup() {
        //identify and start WiFi
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
      WiFi.softAPConfig(local_ip, gateway, subnet);
      WiFi.softAP(ssid_ap, password_ap);
      //sanity check
      Serial.begin(115200);
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("IP Address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
      //Configure the server's routes
      server.on("/", handleIndex); //using top root path for last sensor value
      server.on("/update", handleUpdate); //use this to update sensor value
      server.begin();
    }

    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    server.handleClient();
    }

    void handleIndex(){
      server.send(200, "text/plain", String(sensor_value));//need to refresh page to get information
    }

    void handleUpdate(){
      //value is passed by an URL argument
      sensor_value = server.arg("value").toFloat();
      Serial.println(sensor_value);
      server.send(200,"text/plain", "Updated");
    }
```

Comment: You should be using `WiFi.softAPIP();` to get the AP IP address.

Comment: Ya I know this but I am still not getting a reponse from my client. this line isnt becoming true on the client.
        Serial.println("Response: ");
          while(client.available()){
            String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
            Serial.print(line);

Comment: Have you tried just running the WiFiAccessPoint example?

Comment: Comment // WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP); You dont need it with softAP

Answer (score 1):

The WiFi.localIP() is a function of the STA. To print the IP address of the SoftAP, use WiFi.softAPIP().

Comment: this is the answer to the question, code and output in the question. if you want to ask why the client can't connect, ask with the code and output of the client